# How to update SparseBooleanArray key values when I remove multiple items from a ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with an ArrayAdapter.

I select multiple items and I try to delete them from Database, and ListView.

I have put delete in a action mode contextual menu and I delete as below:

```
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete)
     {
     SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
     short size = (short)selected.size();

     for (byte I = 0; I<size; I++)
         {
         if (selected.valueAt(I))
            {
            Contact selectedItem = adapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(I));
            boolean number = mHelper.deleteCont(myList.get(selected.keyAt(I)).getId());
            adapter.remove(selectedItem);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
          }

           // Close CAB (Contextual Action Bar)
           mode.finish();
}
```

BUT if I have chosen 3 listview elements to Delete with one position difference among them then **the key of SparseBooleanArray (which is the position of element)** DOES NOT corresponds to a valid element.

**How I am going to put in the keys of the SparseBooleanArray a unique id coming from a database?**

The SparseBooleanArray in adapter is the following:

```
public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}
```

Comment: Use real ids ... not position

Answer (score 2):

**SPARSE** boolean array, unlike a regular boolean array (`boolean[]`) is meant to be used when your integer index is not necessarily uniform, such as in the case of numeric IDs.

You should use a numeric ID for every item in the `SparseBooleanArray` rather than simply the index of the item. This should solve your problem by simply removing the ID that was removed from the `SparseBooleanArray` and not worrying about the index.

Just make sure each element has a unique integer ID, and then use that when adding it to the `SparseBooleanArray`.

Comment: Yes ok but, while trying its passing only one unique integer for one selected item and not ids for multiple items

Comment: Ok I managed to pass all the selected values but Contact selectedItem = adapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(I)); is not working because it needs the position to fetch the particular item, Should I concatenate the unique id with position?

Comment: You should have a method to fetch position by id - basically it goes over the item list, comparing ID, then returns the index of the item in the list for the item that matches the given ID.